# How to import a whole class in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I can't get it right (nor wrong either way)

I have a folder structure like:

```
/index.html
/js/app.js
/js/sonic.js
...
```

In index.html has `<script type="module" src="./js/app.js"></script>`

In sonic.js has `export class Sonic { ... }`

And app.js: `import { Sonic } from "./sonic.js";`

Tried `import "./sonic.js";`, `export default class Sonic { ... }` to no avail.

VSCode autocompletes the import part as "./sonic", so i have to add ".js" extension manualy so
DevTools stop giving me 404 error. And as it does autocompletes, i presume the export works.
So what i'm missing?

Comment: Ignore VSCode autocompletion, yes you do need the `.js` extension to correctly refer to the URL from which the module can be loaded by the browser. What you have (`export class Sonic {…}` and `import { Sonic } from "./sonic.js";`) should be working (the other tries don't), what exactly is the error you are getting? What do you mean by "*I can't get it right*"? How are you using `Sonic` in *app.js*?

Comment: What is not working? In the webpage or the VSCode editor? I assume you are running a local web server?

Comment: This works in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-qt7eth?file=index.html), but there's a bit of pre-processing

Comment: If you want to post additional code, you can [edit] your question - please don't put it in comments

Comment: @Bergi: app.js does let sonic = new sonic(3);

Comment: Well change that to `let sonic = new Sonic(3);` - casing matters! Again, what error are you getting, what part of the code doesn't work as expected?

Comment: I'm sorry, i typed it in lowercase but i got right here: Sonic(3)